# NASM - Section .data is not working as expected

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, x86-16, bootloader

I am learning about the bootloaders, and I used this code from here https://wiki.osdev.org/Babystep2 to create 'Hello,World!' bootloader.

```
; boot.asm
   mov ax, 0x07c0
   mov ds, ax
 
   mov si, msg
   cld
ch_loop:lodsb
   or al, al ; zero=end or str
   jz hang   ; get out
   mov ah, 0x0E
   mov bh, 0
   int 0x10
   jmp ch_loop
 
hang:
   jmp hang
 
msg   db 'Hello World', 13, 10, 0
   times 510-($-$$) db 0
   db 0x55
   db 0xAA
```

The above code works perfectly fine. But when I tried to modify it to use the standard NASM syntax as below, it prints nothing and there are no error messages!

```
section .data
    msg:    db 'Hello, World!', 13, 10, 0

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov ax, 0x07c0
    mov ds, ax
    mov si, msg
    cld
    
_ch_loop:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz _hang
    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov bh, 0
    int 0x10
    jmp _ch_loop

_hang:
    jmp _hang
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    db 0x55
    db 0xAA
```

The above code doesn't print anything and there is no error message. However when I run the below code it works!

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    msg:    db 'Hello, World!', 13, 10, 0
    mov ax, 0x07c0
    mov ds, ax
    mov si, msg
    cld
    
_ch_loop:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz _hang
    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov bh, 0x00
    int 0x10
    jmp _ch_loop

_hang:
    jmp _hang
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    db 0x55
    db 0xAA
```

What is going wrong here. Why `section .data` is not working as expected?

Comment: The BIOS jumps to the first byte of your boot sector.  If that's data, the CPU will be deconding those ASCII codes as opcodes.  The MBR flat binary format doesn't have a program-loader that can handle sections, so this is exactly how you should expect it to work, not like making a Linux executable.  Single-step your code with a debugger like BOCHS to see how it executes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try debugging using Bochs!

Comment: If you assemble this using NASM to create a binary file directly, NASM will reorganize the sections. The `.data` section by default will follow .`text`. In the second snippet of code that fails to work correctly because the `.data` section will be placed after the boot signature and that is outside the first sector. When your code goes to print the string nothing will appear since data beyond the first sector isn't read into memory.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Reorganization of code by assembler was causing the misbehaviour. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation Sir and my confusion is clear now...

Comment: Did you set up a linker and link it properly. Nasm has nothing to do with sections and LD dose.